# Facebook sign in on android not working

Tags: java, android, facebook, callback

When a user tries to log in via **Facebook** in my app, the callback fails with the following **error**:

```
Exception: SERVER_ERROR: 
[code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing query. 
[extra]: Errors while executing operation "ProxyAuthAppLoginQuery": 
At Query.proxy_auth_app_login: Failed to resolve field.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: did you figure this out. Same problem